# Find and replace in visual studio with regular expressions

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I am trying to do a find and replace for anything that matches this:

```
toastr.success((.*));
```

Which matches this:

```
toastr.success('The user has been created.');
```

So far so good, now I want to replace everything except the text. So I want the end result to be this:

```
ngNotify('The user has been created.', { type: 'success' });
```

I have tried doing this:

```
ngNotify((.*), { type: 'success' });
```

Now I realise this is probably not supported, so I just want to know if there is a way of doing this before I start manually replacing each item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
toastr\.success\((.*)\);
```

and replace with

```
ngNotify($1, { type: 'success' });
```

**Details**:

- `toastr\.success\(` - matches literal `toastr.success(` text
- `(.*)` - captures any 0+ chars other than line break chars into Group 1 (later referred to with the `$1` backreference)
- `\);` - literal `);` text.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TErMtk/2).

VS test:

[image]

Comment: Actually, I think I got it with the find being `toastr.success\('(.*)\'\);` and the replace being `ngNotify.set('$1', { type: 'success' });`

Comment: Just a sec, I am launching a VS instance.... BTW, note that `.*` matches chars greedily, as many as possible. That is, it won't work if you have several `;` separated calls/declarations/etc. on a line.

Comment: @r3plica: I added a VS2015 screenshot.